# MySQL - quering several records based on delimited string

Tags: mysql, delimited

i'm having the following table named "features":

```
id  feature
-----------------------
1   aa
2   bb
3   cc
4   dd
5   ee
6   ff
```

is there a way to query this table based on a delimited string?
something like:

```
select * from features where {some magic here} = "1,4,5"
```

which should return only the corresponding records?

Comment: Here's the [`documentation`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `IN` keyword, which makes it possible to use a set of values instead of whatever you tried. For this example it would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM features WHERE id IN (1,4,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using IN:-

```
select * 
from features where id IN (1,4,5)
```

Or do you mean a passed string?

Answer (score 1):

Use IN clause like this:

```
select * from features where id IN(1,4,5);
```

or

```
select * from features where feature IN ('aa','dd','ee');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a 100% sure I know what you're asking - are you trying to pull all records matching a set of IDs or looking for a Feature containing a particular string?

For the former:

```
select * from features where id in (1,4,5);
```

For the latter:

```
select * from features where feature like '%1,4,5%';
```